# How to export const defined inside setTimeout in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Beginner here,
I have a setTimeout configured something like this that parses json from session storage

```js
  setTimeout(() => {
    const blog = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.blogs);
    console.log(blog);
  }, 1000)
```

all I want to do is use the blog const outside the timeout which would make things easier,

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    const blog = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.blogs);
  }, 1000)    
console.log(blog); <------ this does not work
```

I get the Undefined error

```
'blog' is not defined  no-undef
```

Comment: Even if you define `blog` outside the arrow function the `console.log()` line will always run before the timeout completes. This definitely feels like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Why are you reading from the session storage in a `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0):

If you need it outside, you'll need

- to use state so you can set the state inside the timeout callback
- to log it only when it gets initialized, and not on every render, use `useEffect` with it in the dependency array

```
const [blog, setBlog] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setBlog(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.blogs));
  }, 1000);
}, []); // run only once, on mount
useEffect(() => {
  if (blog) { // only log once it exists
    console.log(blog);
  }
}, [blog]); // run only when the state changes
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `Promise` to help you to fix this problem.

```js
const [blog, setBlog] = useState()
new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const sessionBlog = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.blogs);
    resolve(sessionBlog);
  }, 1000)
}).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
  setBlog(res);
})

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('blog has changed, you can do whatever you want here')
}, [blog])
```

Comment: It does but could you help me with on how would I now use `res` outside `Promise`

Comment: I have updated the code, you can get the latest `blog` in `useEffect`.

Answer (score -2):

That's because setTimeout is async, your console.log will run first before the setTimeout (even if it is 0 seconds)..

Answer (score -4):

How about this

```
let blog;
setTimeout(() => {
    blog = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.blogs);
  }, 1000)    
console.log(blog);
```

Comment: Test this, ofc it doesn't work

Comment: doesn't work sadly.

Comment:  have you used sessionStorage b4 ? I copy AND paste yow code, i thought you already knew where the err was